downloading a file using python without knowing the file type (file name + file type)
I have been trying to download a file from the American Gut Project in qiita (study number 10317).
I can download directly from the web, however I want to create a python code to download the files automatically. This is the url from the site I need to download from: https://qiita.ucsd.edu/study/description/10317
and this is the data I need to download:
https://qiita.ucsd.edu/download_raw_data/10317.
As you might see, the ending of the file I want to download is not a <path/to/website/file_name.file_type>.
because the download url is not as specified above, I couldn't use the requests library to download it
`req = requests.get(download_url)
filename = req.url[downloadurl.rfind('/')+1:]
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
for chunk in req.iter_content(chunk):
if chunk:
f.write(chunk)`
correction and clarification:
The problem here is that when I try to download the file I get an html file describing the content of the download link.
One of the issues that came to light thanks to the user chepner, is that when trying to use the link it redirects the user to the https://qiita.ucsd website. Is there a way to bypass that? Is there a solution in order to download the file in python?
Thanks in advance!

Your question is confusing.  What is the actual problem here?  Do you not know what url to use to download the content?  Do you not know what filename to use to save the content locally?  And why does the file type matter at all?  Content is content.

You can download it, and the file system doesn't care what you name it (file extensions are descriptive, not prescriptive).

Your bigger problem (based on my attempt to view the given URL) is that you need to authenticate the request; I'm being redirected to https://qiita.ucsd.edu, which has little to do with using requests or a web browser.

I understand the issue you're facing. To automate the download using Python despite the redirection to the authentication page, you can use Selenium, a tool for automating web browsers. Below is a Python code snippet that demonstrates how you can achieve this:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

# Set up Chrome options to specify the download directory and enable automatic download
download_dir = "/path/to/download/folder"  # Replace with your desired download directory

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {
    "download.default_directory": download_dir,
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,  # Disable download prompt
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,     # Ensure directory is updated if changed
    "safebrowsing.enabled": True            # Enable safe browsing to avoid blocking
}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

# Initialize the WebDriver with the specified options
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/path/to/chromedriver', options=options)

try:
    # Step 1: Go to the login page
    driver.get('https://qiita.ucsd.edu/')

    # Step 2: Locate and fill in the login form
    username = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'login_field')  # Replace with actual ID of the username field
    password = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'password')     # Replace with actual ID of the password field

    username.send_keys('your_username')  # Replace with your username
    password.send_keys('your_password')  # Replace with your password
    password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)      # Submit the form

    # Step 3: Wait for the welcome phrase to appear in the navigation bar
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    welcome_phrase = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="navigation-bar"]/div/div[2]/ul[2]/li[1]/a')))

    # Step 4: Go to the download page
    driver.get('https://qiita.ucsd.edu/download_raw_data/10317')

    # The download should start automatically.
    time.sleep(10)  # Wait for the download to complete

finally:
    # Close the driver
    driver.quit()

You can change the default directory where you want to save this file automatically  :
download_dir = "/path/to/download/folder" 

Make sure to replace 'path_to_chromedriver_executable' with the actual path to your ChromeDriver executable. And if you want to use headless browser, you can add it as option on the driver options we have defined.

will this work for any user using this code?
what I mean by that is I try to create a python code to add to a library that will download those files automatically. will It work then?
In addition, is there a way to make the password and username private so that users won't be able to access my account?
thanks in advance
